# When is a extension of $\mathbb{Z}$ by a free group a CAT(0) group?

Tags: gr.group-theory, gt.geometric-topology, geometric-group-theory, alexandrov-geometry

The question has an easy answer, if one replaces free by free abelian: Then the resulting group is always solvable and a solvable subgroup of a CAT(0) group is virtually abelian.
If the resulting was CAT(0), then the chosen automorphism $\varphi$ in $\mathbb{Z}^n\rtimes_\varphi \mathbb{Z}$ would have finite order - otherwise the group would not be virtually abelian.

Now one can ask the same question for the free group instead or the free abelian group. 
I would like to know for which automorphisms $\varphi$ of the free group $F_n$ the group $F_n\rtimes_\varphi \mathbb{Z}$ is CAT(0).

I only know, that $F_n \times \mathbb{Z}$ is CAT(0). I think that if the chosen automorphism has finite order, then the result should be CAT(0) (although I don't have a proof). And I do not know automorphism, that gives a non-CAT(0) group.

Comment: If the automorphism is finite order then it can be realised by a combinatorial automorphism of a graph. (This basically follows from Stallings' Ends Theorem.) The resulting mapping torus is CAT(0).

Answer (score 21):

An example of a free-by-cyclic group that is not CAT(0) was [given](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?pg1=IID&s1=190275&vfpref=html&r=18&mx-pid=1195719) by Gersten.  It is constructed from the automorphism of $F_3\cong\langle a,b,c\rangle$ that sends

$a\mapsto a,~b\mapsto ba,~ c\mapsto ca^2~.$

The idea of the proof is to think about translation lengths and flats in any CAT(0) space on which it acts.  As $\langle a,t\rangle\cong\mathbb{Z}^2$, it stabilises some flat.  But $t$, $at$ and $a^2t$ are all conjugate, so have the same translation lengths.  A little thought shows that this is impossible in a flat.

Note that, in many respects, (fg free)-by-cyclic groups are difficult to distinguish from CAT(0) groups.  For instance, they have [quadratic isoperimetric inequality](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?arg3=&co4=AND&co5=AND&co6=AND&co7=AND&dr=all&pg4=AUCN&pg5=AUCN&pg6=PC&pg7=ALLF&pg8=ET&review_format=html&s4=bridson%252C%2520m%2a&s5=groves&s6=&s7=&s8=All&vfpref=html&yearRangeFirst=&yearRangeSecond=&yrop=eq&r=2&mx-pid=2590896).

---

As pointed out in [this](http://berstein.wordpress.com/2011/02/05/non-positively-curved-groups-i-cat0-and-cat-1-groups/) blog post, the question

> Which free-by-cyclic groups are CAT(0)?

is Question 7.9 of [Bridson's AIM article](http://www.aimath.org/pggt/Hyperbolic_and_CAT%280%29_Groups?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=bridson-version1.pdf) about `Problems concerning hyperbolic and CAT(0) groups'.

Comment: Here, $t$ is the stable letter, of course.

Answer (score 14):

You'll find some examples of CAT(0) free-by-cyclics in

Samuelson, "[On CAT(0) structures for free-by-cyclic groups](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~psamuelson/preprints.html)"

and

Barnard and Brady, "Distorsion of surface groups in CAT(0) free-by-cyclic groups"

Comment: For future reference, there is a free version of the first paper mentioned <a href="http://www.math.cornell.edu/~psamuelson/preprints.html"> here</a>
It is essentially identical to the published version.

Comment: Sorry, I messed up the link... here's one that works: http://www.math.cornell.edu/~psamuelson/preprints.html

Answer (score 13):

If you take the mapping torus of an automorphism of a surface with boundary, then it has a non-positively curved metric by a [result of Leeb](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1358977). Such automorphisms though will be sparse in the set of all automorphisms of a free group (except in rank 2, as noted in a paper of [Brady](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1334311)).

Answer (score 10):

Seems worth recording here: there are some recent new examples of CAT(0) free-by-cyclic groups due to Rylee Lyman, see https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.03097v3. As she explains, "*These are the first families comprising infinitely many examples for each rank of the nonabelian free group.*" Also, they're not relatively hyperbolic, which contrasts with the hyperbolic Hagen-Wise examples.

Answer (score 7):

In [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/1311.2084) paper Mark F. Hagen and Daniel T. Wise show that a hyperbolic, free-by-cyclic group whose monodromy is irreducible acts geometrically on a CAT(0) cube complex. Hyperbolicity means for such groups that the automorphism does not fix the conjugacy class of a nontrivial word by [Brinkmanns Theorem](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/PL00001647), which can be found in *Hyperbolic automorphisms of free groups*.

Comment: It is nice to hear a general statement like this!

Comment: Not quite - they also assume that the monodromy is irreducible, although they say they are working on removing that hypothesis.