# Hyperbolicity of a semidirect product

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory

Let F be a finitely generated free group and let $\gamma : F \rightarrow F$ be an automorphism. Is the semidirect product $F \rtimes  \mathbb{Z}$ an hyperbolic group? where $\mathbb{Z}$ acts in F via $\gamma$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Bestvina-Feighn combination theorem says that this is true if and only if $\gamma$ has no nontrivial periodic conjugacy classes.  See

MR1152226 (93d:53053) 
Bestvina, M.(1-UCLA); Feighn, M.(1-RTG2)
A combination theorem for negatively curved groups. 
J. Differential Geom. 35 (1992), no. 1, 85–101.

Comment: Is this semidirect product a CAT(0) group?

Comment: There are free-by-cyclics which are not CAT(0): S.M. Gersten, The automorphism group of a free group is not a CAT(0) group, Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 121 (4) (1994) 999–1002

Comment: See also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/53973/when-is-a-extension-of-mathbbz-by-a-free-group-a-cat0-group

Comment: I have one more question, If $\gamma$ is induced by a diffeomorphism $f: M\rightarrow M$ where M is a compact 2 manifold with boundary and $\pi_1 (M)$ is isomorphic to F, then my initial demidirect product is hyperbolic?

Comment: The answer to this last question is that it never is (hyperbolic) --  in this case f fixes the boundary components (as a set), which easily gives you a torus, which is $\pi_1$-injective, and so you're not hyperbolic, by the easy half of Andy's answer.