# General properties of free-by-cyclic groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, gt.geometric-topology, geometric-group-theory

I admit this is a *very* broad question, but I am looking for general properties of **[finitely generated free]-by-[infinite cyclic]** groups. More precisely, what are some properties that the groups $\{F_n\rtimes_\phi\mathbb{Z}\ |\ n\geq 2,\ \phi\in Aut(F_n)\}$ have in common?

These are some properties that *not* all of those groups have (even though some do):

1. They are not all hyperbolic.
2. They are not all $\mathrm{CAT}(0)$ groups.

These are some properties that the groups *do* have in common:

1. They all have solvable conjugacy problem.
2. They all satisfy a quadratic isoperimetric inequality.

Furthermore for $n=2$, all groups of the form $F_2\rtimes_\phi\mathbb{Z}$ are strongly poly-free. This will not be true in higher rank however, as for $n\geq 3$ not all automorphisms of $F_n$ are geometric.

I understand that the structure of $F_n\rtimes_\phi\mathbb{Z}$ highly depends on $\phi$, so fully understanding all common properties probably boils down to fully understanding $Aut(F_n)$.

Comment: If you are interested in analytic properties: they all have the Haagerup property.

Comment: As this question seems to be asking for a list, perhaps it should be community wiki.

Comment: I agree with HW, why don't you CW the question?

Comment: Here's a related question (which I'm sure you've seen): http://mathoverflow.net/questions/53973/when-is-a-extension-of-mathbbz-by-a-free-group-a-cat0-group

Answer (score 4):

Well, you can turn any theorem about these groups into a property. For instance: $F_n \rtimes_\phi \mathbb{Z}$ satisfies the property ``hyperbolic if and only if no $\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$ subgroups''. That's Brinkmann's theorem.

Answer (score 4):

[Feighn and Handel](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?arg3=&co4=AND&co5=AND&co6=AND&co7=AND&dr=all&pg4=AUCN&pg5=AUCN&pg6=PC&pg7=ALLF&pg8=ET&review_format=html&s4=feighn&s5=handel&s6=&s7=&s8=All&vfpref=html&yearRangeFirst=&yearRangeSecond=&yrop=eq&r=6&mx-pid=1709311) proved that they're all coherent in 'Mapping tori of free group automorphisms are coherent', *Ann. of Math. (2)* 149 (1999), no. 3, 1061--1077.

Answer (score 2):

They all have cohomological dimension $2$.

The upper bound follows easily from the Serre spectral sequence, the lower bound follows from the fact that groups of cohomological dimension $1$ are free groups. This last fact can be proved without using this big theorem by computing $H^*(G,\mathbf ZG)$ : it is concentrated in dimension 2 and is a free abelian group ... in particular your groups are duality groups (but rarely Poincaré duality groups).

Edit : sorry, I answered too quickly ... the group $H^2(G,\mathbf ZG)$ does not need to be a free abelian group. Thus your groups need not be duality groups.

Answer (score 2):

1. They are all residually finite.
2. They are *not* all subgroup separable/LERF.
3. They do *not* all have decidable submonoid membership problem.

Residual finiteness is a result which can be found in the (aptly named) [G. Baumslag, "Finitely generated cyclic extensions of free groups are residually finite" (Bull. Amer. Math. Soc., 5, 87-94, 1971)].

The facts on the submonoid membership problem and subgroup separability/LERF follow from the following example: the free-by-cyclic one-relator group $$G = \langle a, t \mid [a, tat^{-1}] = 1 \rangle \cong \langle a, b, t \mid a^t = ab, b^t = b \rangle$$ embeds the right-angled Artin group $A(P_4)$ (see [this](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00222-019-00920-2) article), which is known to have undecidable submonoid membership problem. It is shown that $G$ is not subgroup separable/LERF in [R.G. Burns, A. Karrass, and D. Solitar, *A note on groups with separable finitely generated subgroups*, Bull. Aust. Math. Soc. 36 (1987), 153–160].